# I change the encoding file but the content of file changed to symbols i want to restore the file content

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

i also change .android.X.X to old and reopen AS but dose't restore the content can i restore the content ?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV9TQ.jpg)

Comment: how you end up to this level of encoding? Strange never seen before

Comment: file was loaded in the wrong encoding utf-8, when i search for this message i found answer that tell click encoding in other and click more choose utf-8 , and i click reload not convert then i end up to this